# Angular 8 bind ngrx state to component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx

I am new to Angular and I want to bind some Classnames in my HTML to some values in my states. At first I had only one state, which was only some boolean value and everything worked fine. Now I changed the state to an object, so that I can save more information in it. Although I am using more or less the same approach as before but the classname doesn't change. The state does change. Can someone please tell me what my mistake is and if there is another more appropriate way to do the things I am trying to do please tell me that also.

The angular version is 8.2.14.

This is my code:

reducer.ts:

```
export type ShoppinCartState = {
  CartIsOpen: boolean;
};

export type HamburgerState = {
  MenuIsOpen: boolean;
};

export function hamburgerReducer(
  state: HamburgerState = { MenuIsOpen: false },
  action: Action
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "HAMBURGER.TOGGLE":
      console.log("HAMBURGER.Toggle called " + state.MenuIsOpen);
      return {
        ...state,
        MenuIsOpen: !state.MenuIsOpen
      };
    case "HAMBURGER.CLOSE":
      return {
        ...state,
        MenuIsOpen: false
      };
    case "HAMBURGER.OPEN":
      return {
        ...state,
        MenuIsOpen: true
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function shoppingCartReducer(
  state: ShoppinCartState = { CartIsOpen: false },
  action: Action
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CART.TOGGLE":
      console.log("Tooggle cart called " + state.CartIsOpen);
      return {
        ...state,
        CartIsOpen: !state.CartIsOpen
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This is my Component. When the user clicks on the Hamburger Icon one action is dispatched which changes the state. There is also another part which is binded to the state. When the value is true, the classname should be "visible".

```
<app-hamburger-icon (click)="onHamburgerIconClick()"></app-hamburger-icon>
  <div id="Logo"><a (click)="onLinkClick()" routerLink="/">E99-EsAns</a></div>
  <ul [ngClass]="{ visible: hamburgerClicked$ | async }">
```

And that's the component.ts file

```
import { Store } from "@ngrx/store";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { HamburgerState } from "src/app/reducer";

@Component({
  selector: "app-navigationbar",
  templateUrl: "./navigationbar.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./navigationbar.component.css"]
})
export class NavigationbarComponent implements OnInit {
  hamburgerClicked$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private store: Store<HamburgerState>) {
    this.hamburgerClicked$ = this.store.select("MenuIsOpen");
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  onHamburgerIconClick() {
    console.log(this.hamburgerClicked$);
    this.store.dispatch({ type: "HAMBURGER.TOGGLE" });
  }

  onLinkClick() {
    this.store.dispatch({ type: "HAMBURGER.CLOSE" });
  }

  onShoppingCartIconClicked() {
    this.store.dispatch({ type: "CART.TOGGLE" });
  }
}
```

Some snippet of my app.module.ts

```
import { hamburgerReducer, shoppingCartReducer } from "./reducer";
...
...
...
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      hamburgerReducer: hamburgerReducer,
      shoppingCartReducer: shoppingCartReducer
    })
  ],
```

Comment: Everything is combined to one global state. So there a not two separate states. In your `app.module.ts` you should have something like `StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, ...` or a probably a global `State` interface that tells you the structure of your store. You probably need to select via a selector function that is given the complete state object `this.store.select(state => state.hamburgers.MenuIsOpen)`

Comment: Okay... I tried following `  constructor(private store: Store<HamburgerState>) {
    this.hamburgerClicked$ = this.store.select(
      state => state.MenuIsOpen
    );
  }`  but it still doesn't work ...

Comment: try `state.hamburgerReducer.MenuIsOpen` and remove the type `HamburgerState` from `Store<HamburgerState`>. Go with `any` during testing

Comment: When I type state.hamburgerReducer.MenuIsOpen Visual Studio Code tells me that hamburgerReducer does not exist on type 'HamburgerState' ... but It works now... So strange behavior. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The type `HamburgerSate` is wrong in `Store<HamburgerState>`. Go with `any` or better define an interface `State` that describes your global store structure.

Comment: Okay i will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inject the `Store` into a component you operate on the structure of the global state. So the select has to 'select' into this structure to access the correct object.

Only the reducer functions get handed a slice of this global state. We can see that most likely in `app.module.ts` where you define your store:

```
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      hamburgerReducer: hamburgerReducer,
      shoppingCartReducer: shoppingCartReducer
    })
```

Best practice is to create a interface `State` that describes your store structure:

```
export interface State {
   hamburgerReducer: HamburgerState;
   shoppingCartReducer: ShoppingCartState;
}
```

and then use this interface when injecting the store:

```
constructor(private store: Store<State>)
```

then you can select the hamburger menu-state via:

```
this.store.select(state => state.hamburgerReducer.MenuIsOpen)
```

Comment: I have tried this out but sadly I get following error on reloading the page : TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_co.shoppingCartState$.CartIsOpen')... Something seems to be not defined on loading